# use of if else in linux to find whether the folder exists or not

Tags: bash, shell-script, mkdir

I have the following bash script:

```
if [ -d "/$home/DB_handouts"] then
 echo "Directory DB_handouts found"
else
mkdir /$home/DB_handouts
 chmod 777 /$home/DB_handouts
fi
```

Running the above code produces an error:

```
./file.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./file.sh: line 12: `   else'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: By the way, `mkdir` **has a way to set mode**: `mkdir -m 777 /$home/DB_handouts`. So you command can be written in this way: `mkdir -m 700 test 2>/dev/null || echo "Directory DB_handouts found"`

Comment: If `$home` is your user's home directory, then use `$HOME` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your script:

- there has to be a `;` between the `]` and `then` (as @heemayl also indicated) or `then` should be put on a line of its own
- there has to be a space between `handouts"` and `]`
- you should (but this doesn't generate an error) consistently indent, or use the `-m` option for `mkdir` (as @skwlisp indicated)

something like:

```
if [ -d "/$home/DB_handouts" ] 
then
  echo "Directory DB_handouts found"
else
  mkdir -m 777 /$home/DB_handouts
fi
```

The above of course assumes that `/$home` exists, the whole thing can be much more easily achieved by using:

```
mkdir -p -m 777 /$home/DB_handouts
```

With `-p` there will be no complaints if the directory already exists.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a semicolon (`;`) between `if [ -d "/$home/DB_handouts"]` and `then` (or put `then` in a new line):

```
if [ -d "/$home/DB_handouts" ]; then
```

Also in your case check if `mkdir -p` would do the job. Looking at the example i think the following should work:

```
mkdir -p /foo/bar
chmod 777 /foo/bar
```

Comment: then  a new error came as ./file.sh: line 10: [: missing `]',the full code is this `#!/bin/bash
#OUTFILE=out.xml
prefix='u'
INFILE=inputfile.txt

for i in $(cat $INFILE) ; do
    usern=$prefix""$i
    home=/home/""$usern
    
   if [ -d "/$home/DB_handouts"];  then
  echo "Directory DB_handouts found"""$usern
 else
  mkdir -m 777 /$home/DB_handouts
 echo "Folder created"
 fi

    
done
`

Comment: @Ann you need a space before closing `]` i.e. `if [ -d "/$home/DB_handouts" ]; then`